Validating parameters - param type and name (getParameters() function; framework)
I am taking a PHP course and I have a question about conditions when checking the correctness of type parameters in Container class. Here I have a code fragment from the Container class:
public function resolve(string $className)
  {
    $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($className);

    if (!$reflectionClass->isInstantiable()) {
      throw new ContainerException("Class {$className} is not instantiable");
    }

    $constructor = $reflectionClass->getConstructor();

    if (!$constructor) {
      return new $className;
    }

    $parameters = $constructor->getParameters();

    if (count($parameters) === 0) {
      return new $className;
    }

    $dependencies = [];

    foreach ($parameters as $param) {
      $name = $param->getName();
      $type = $param->getType();

      if (!$type) {
        throw new ContainerException("Failed to resolve class {$className} because param name {$name} is missing");
      }

      if (!$type instanceof ReflectionNamedType || $type->isBultin()) {
        throw new ContainerException("Failed to resolve class {$className} because invalid param name");
      }
    }

    dd($parameters);
  }

Why do we check the validity of parameter types in conditions, but refer to their names in container exceptions?

The question is not clear. You can put whatever you want in exception messages. They are just meant to provide useful information to understand the error.

I know that but if we have such condition if (!$type instanceof ReflectionNamedType || $type->isBultin()) where we refer to the type, why does the author refer to the name in the message?

Well the message could be better, I agree it's not great. But more importantly, the code is wrong because of the typo: isBultin instead of isBuiltin.

thank you for pointing out the typo

If you listen carefully, the author mention that the message for example
